# How to get data from minus operator

Tags: sql, oracle

My first select query gives count of 20994 and second select query gives count of 20993 when execute separately but when I execute by using minus operator then it gives 105 count. It should give only one record which does not exist in second select query from first select query.

```
select distinct subs_id,ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE from subscriber_profile_billing  where ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE='VPTs'
minus
(select  subs_id,decode(ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE,'VPT','VPTs','VPTs','VPTs')   from subscriber_profile where ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE like 'VP%'
union
select  subs_id,decode(ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE,'VPT','VPTs','VPTs','VPTs')   from subscriber_profile_his where ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE like 'VP%');
```

Comment: What sqlverion are you using as u say MySQL, SQL-Server and PLSQL

Comment: Removed the irrelevant and conflicting tags. Pls add the one database product tag that you actually use! It cannot be mysql as it does not support the minus operator.

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY` clauses in the above when you don't have any aggregation?

Comment: It *can't* be SQL Server either, as T-SQL also does not have a `MINUS` operator, doesn't allow derived tables not to be named, and `decode` isn't a built-in function (if it were user defined function, it would have to be schema qualified). That, presumably, means the above is Oracle? Or was the PL/SQL tag completely irrelevant too?

Comment: "...It should give only one record..."  -- No. Oracle will remove in the first query all rows from the second query. For example if the first query returns (1, 2, 3, 4) and the second returns (4, 4, 5, 6), then `MINUS` will remove only `4`; the result will be (1, 2, 3).

Comment: `minus` is a set difference: `A minus B` is all elements (rows) of `A` that are not exist in `B`. It's not a difference of cardinalities (counts)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see which row from billing table (with ATTR = 'VPTs') does not have matching row within unioned tables profile and profile_his (having ATTR that starts with 'VP') - you can get it using Left Join.
Simplified sample data:

```sql
WITH
    subs_profile_billing AS
        (
            Select 100 "SUBS_ID", 'VPTs' "ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select 200 "SUBS_ID", 'VPTs' "ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select 300 "SUBS_ID", 'XPTs' "ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE" From Dual
        ),
```

... billing data

| SUBS_ID | ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | VPTs |
| 200 | VPTs |
| 300 | XPTs |

```sql
    subs_profile AS
        (
            Select 100 "SUBS_ID", 'RPT-Z03' "ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE" From Dual 
        ),
    subs_profile_his AS
        (
            Select 100 "SUBS_ID", 'VPT-XYZ03' "ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE" From Dual 
        )
```

... unioned profile and profile_his data

| SUBS_ID | ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | RPT-Z03 |
| 100 | VPT-XYZ03 |

There are two IDs (100 and 200) with ATTR = 'VPTs' in billings data and just one ID (100) within unioned data having ATTR that starts with 'VP'. Below is SQL that results with the billing row that has no match within unioned data:

```sql
SELECT  b.SUBS_ID "BILLING_SUBS_ID", b.ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE "BILLING_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE"
FROM    subs_profile_billing b
Left Join
    ( Select * From subs_profile  Union All
      Select * From subs_profile_his 
    ) p ON(p.SUBS_ID = b.SUBS_ID And SubStr(p.ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE, 1, 2) =  'VP')
WHERE b.ATTR_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE = 'VPTs' And p.SUBS_ID Is Null  -- this Null means there is no match
```

R e s u l t :

| BILLING_SUBS_ID | BILLING_SERVICE_SUB_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | VPTs |